# Lightweight, simple but effective pie-chart or clock in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pie-chart

I'm trying to find a suitable clock or pie chart JQuery plugin which will visualize info based on an earlier selection made by a user.

Basically, the user will select a number of 'minutes'.
The clock itself will do nothing, but the background will change to highlight the amount of minutes chosen.  i.e. The attached image below shows the results for 10, 30 and 60 minutes respectively.

[image]

I was thinking of pie charts because they can easily be manipulated to give this effect, and i could (maybe) overlay an image or something to make it look like a clock!

I'd also love if it could be animated using an onClick, but this is desirable and I must get it working first! :)

Have you seen something like this before?  Any plugins I have found are either way too advanced or not suitable :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be overkill for what you looking to do (and I'm not entirely sure you could do exactly what you want because I haven't worked with it) but you could look at [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/)

Comment: Great find!  Yes the library is way too extensive but I'm sure I can shave bits off here and there as most of it is not for pie-charts, but bar and line charts, etc. I just changed some parameters, set some dynamilally generated div's to display:none (so that extra features do not show) and I overlaid an image with transparancy.  Hey presto!  Here is a sample of what I did: http://jsfiddle.net/UvtkF/

Answer (score 0):

If you have fixed times eg. 15,30,45,60 minutes than use 4 background images as sprite and move them by css. For me this should be the simplest solution.

Comment: No unfortunately! The time is actually determined by an algorithm so could be anywhere from 1-60sec.  I could change this to 5 minute increments and use different images but bandwidth is a big factor for me as I am developing primarily for mobile.

Comment: Idea: use a image for 1 degree, copy it use `rotate` from jQuery and display it in other `z-index` in this way you have less bandwith but more client performance...